# How do you check if two commits differ only in code formatting

Tags: java, git, github, version-control, checkstyle

I was trying to add java checkstyle to a hugh project and got arounf 7000 errors, I figured `formatting` the whole project will get rid of 5000 errors.

The problem is that my team refused to review this commit (on git) since it is a hugh change. Is there a way/script to easily figure out if two commits differ only in code formatting and have no logical difference.

Comment: Seems too hard to even try. Just rollback that. I wonder why the team refused...

Comment: Format the before and after with the same formatter (I would use [google-java-format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format), but other tools are clearly available), then just diff them.

Comment: you can also set a coding standard using `eslint`. Also, you can set a build check when you create a PR, so that event if someone forgets to lint the code, the build fails. This way you will have only the coding errors. While the indentation and other syntax related minor coding conventions remain the same.

Comment: `eslint` can also be used to fix all of those code formatting bugs easily.

Comment: It would be nice to make git diff and code-diff products smartly aware/ignore of code style differences and also present differences in the users preferred style

Answer (score 1):

You could start by checking the diff with some [options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_options) to reduce some differences, like

```
git diff --ignore-all-space --allow-indentation-change --ignore-blank-lines HEAD^
```

It won't ignore more complex refactorings, but it's arguable that a good chunk of style changes only affect whitespace and indentation.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Check out one revision into one directory, another revision into another. Apply the same formatting to both directories. Doesn't matter what particular formatting you apply, it should be just the same for both directories.

Then compare directories use a diff tool of your choice like Meld, WinMerge, Diffinity. If they show no difference, then really two revisions have no differences except of formatting.

**Solution 2**

The easier way would be not to compare the revisions, but just format the code: revert the commit, check out the "base line" revision, format the code, commit. Then you will be sure that there are no changes except of formatting.

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to compare the build results (i.e. compile your project and build the JAR or WAR or other artifacts). If you only change formatting, then the resulting bytecode will be equal to the previous one. So a simple bit-by-bit comparison will tell you if no functionality was broken by the formatting change.

Another solution is to just use whatever automated tests you have and run them. Although i assume by the reaction of your team, that you don't have an extensive test coverage.

Comment: Comparing build results can give different results. Class files inside JARs will have different time stamps and thus will be different. WARs that contains JARs will also be different.

Comment: There are tools which can ignore timestamps and just look at the content (i.e. bytecode).